# Getting WaveSurfer.js to work in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to embed [WaveSurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) in an Ionic 3 app.

I tried including the CDN script into the index file and accessing the WaveSurfer variable in the root page constructor.

index.html

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.3.7/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
```

home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

        var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: '#waveform',
            waveColor: 'violet',
            progressColor: 'purple'
        });
    }
}
```

I also tried access this variable through the global window variable (I know this is horrible practice, but I am just building a proof of concept for now)

```
let wavesurfer = window['WaveSurfer'];
```

The WaveSurfer plugin recently started supporting ES6 and think this is a cleaner integration but since I am new to Ionic/Angular I am having problems getting this to work as well.

Comment: are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, use ES6

`npm install --save wavesurfer.js@2.0.0-beta01`

then, in your component

`import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';`

follow [this issue on github](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/761) for an example